# CSS Flexbox Layout - 3 columns and 2 columns interchanging

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Can anyone help me with this layout using Flexbox.
I need a layout that repeats from 3 columns to 2 columns and then back to 3 columns.
Ive added an image below as to what I mean.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use double flex size on each `nth-child(10n + 4)` and `nth-child(10n + 10)` items.

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
  flex: calc(33.33% - 10px);
  height: 70px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #BD1522;
}
.item:nth-child(10n + 4),
.item:nth-child(10n + 10) {
  flex: calc(66.66% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `:nth-child(10n)` & `:nth-child(10n + 4)` are just fine ;) . you can also use `flex:1;` + `min-width` to avoid `cal()` . ;)